# Creating custom jQuery build

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project that uses the jQuery library but we do not need some of the functions. (i.e. effects). Is there anywhere I can make a custom build of the latest jquery library so I can select only the functions I need?

Comment: Why? The standard minified jQuery file is already in everbody's browser cache, so it's not like you could save bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, jQuery is open-source software.  You can [grab the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), fork, modify, etc. as much as you want.  If you need to, you can just download the code from there and do all your customizations locally and not treat it like a forked project.  Either way, the source code includes everything needed to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download the uncompressed version and simple search for the methods you want removed.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js

I would strongly suggest against doing this because it will become cumbersome to maintain. Every time there is an update to the library you'll have to do this.